# Get current category name for new product and best seller widget

Tags: magento2.2

Want to display the category name for each product in new products widget and best sellers widget

I have tried this but not working

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
echo $category->getname();
```

Comment: Hiii TRy my secound method

Comment: Replace $category->getname() BY echo $category->getName();

Comment: Thanks. but still not working.

Comment: using registry to get current category doesn't work on 2.2.x

Comment: then which one works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product       = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId());
$categories    = $product->getCategoryIds();
$cat_name      = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat        = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    $cat_name[] = $cat->getName();
}
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($cat_name);
```

Comment: Not working.Have added this same code under templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml.

Comment: have you modify 2 line as per product collection

Comment: $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId()); here you have to pass your product id

Comment: can you help me to getproduct id

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try again

Comment: Thx Kushal .Its working

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
  <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
?>
```